# Ubuntu Oneiric suddenly beeps constantly

Tags: 11.10, sound, lenovo

I have no idea what happened but sound just broke down on my Lenovo e420s with an intel sound card. All of a sudden there is a constant beep that I can only shut off by muting the computer completely.

I used the alsamixer via command line and determined the source is the "beep" device. Although setting it to the minimum does not turn it off completely.

I found the following in the syslog:

```
Jan 20 16:01:55 fo-tp-krbo pulseaudio[2192]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
Jan 20 16:01:55 fo-tp-krbo pulseaudio[2192]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="29" name="platform-thinkpad_acpi" card_name="alsa_card.platform-thinkpad_acpi" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was caused by a real though temporary hardware malfunction. I started windows and the sound was broken there as well. After having spent the night resting, it started working again...